# In C#, what is the best way to get a list of parent Ids recursively?

Tags: c#, recursion

In C#, I have an **Team** object.

- A team object has an **Id**.
- A team also has attribute called **Parent** which is also a team object

I want to figure out a way where given a team, i have a function that passes in that team and returns an array that includes that team Id as well as all of its parents recursive (parent, grandparent, greatgrandparent, etc) team id.

So for example, lets say i have the following teams

- LowLevelTeam (id = 6)
- NextLevelTeam (id = 10)
- HighLevelTeam (id = 12)

So If i pass in LowLevelTeam, this function would return an array with (6, 10, 12)

If I pass in NextLevelTeam, this function would return an array (10, 12)

If I pass in HighLevelTeam, this function would return an array ( 12)

In my case i have several hundred "levels" but the above example should highlight the request.

Comment: Do you really need a recursive solution? Would an iterative solution work, too? Also, how do I know when I reach the top team? Does it have a parent of -1 or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-recursive solution is really easy.

```
List<int> GetTeamAncestors(Team team)
{
    var ancestors = new List<int>() {team.Id};

    while (team.Parent != null) // how do I know if the team has a parent?
    {
        team = team.Parent;
        ancestors.Add(team.Id);
    }
    return ancestors;
}
```

That's the basic idea.

Comment: You are using the capacity constructor. should be something like `new List<int>{ team.Id }`

Comment: @ArturoMenchaca: Thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be a "yield return" in a recursive procedure like so:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TeamTree
{
    public class Team
    {
        public int Id { get; private set; }
        public Team Parent { get; private set; }

        public Team(int id, Team parent)
        {
            this.Id = id;
            this.Parent = parent;
        }

        public IEnumerable<int> Teams()
        {
            yield return this.Id;

            if (this.Parent != null)
                foreach (int id in Parent.Teams())
                    yield return id;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var highLevelTeam = new Team(12, null);
            var nextLevelTeam = new Team(10, highLevelTeam);
            var lowLevelTeam = new Team(6, nextLevelTeam);

            Console.WriteLine(@"lowLevelTeam ({0})", lowLevelTeam.Teams().Aggregate("", (r, id) => r + ", " + id.ToString()).Substring(2));
            Console.WriteLine(@"nextLevelTeam ({0})", nextLevelTeam.Teams().Aggregate("", (r, id) => r + ", " + id.ToString()).Substring(2));
            Console.WriteLine(@"highLevelTeam ({0})", highLevelTeam.Teams().Aggregate("", (r, id) => r + ", " + id.ToString()).Substring(2));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```